# Functions in scala

Tags: function, scala

I'm having hard time understanding what the following means in scala:

```
f: Int => Int
```

Is the a function?
What is the difference between `f: Int => Int`and `def f(Int => Int)`?

Thanks

Comment: `def f(Int => Int)` isn't valid Scala.  Do you mean `def f(i: Int): Int`?

Comment: Oh okay. I actually know what def `f(i:Int):Int` is. So what is `f: Int => Int`?

Comment: Try `def f(c:Int => Int) = c(_)` which would allow you to `f(_ * 2)(2)` a function that takes a function and produces a function. Interesting when you check the various type signatures.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `f: Int => Int` is a typo of `val f: Int => Int`,
and `def f(Int => Int)` is a typo of `def f(i: Int): Int`.

`val f: Int => Int` means that a value `f` is `Function1[Int, Int]`.

First, `A => B` equals to `=>[A, B]`.
This is just a shortcut writing, for example:

```
trait Foo[A, B]
val foo: Int Foo String // = Foo[Int, String]
```

Second, `=>[A, B]` equals to `Function1[A, B]`.
This is called "type alias", defined like:

```
type ~>[A, B] = Foo[A, B]
val foo: Int ~> String // = Foo[Int, String]
```

`def f(i: Int): Int` is a method, not a function.
But a value `g` is `Function1[Int, Int]` where `val g = f _` is defined.

Comment: The point about methods and functions is valid, but there are some noteworthy stuff here. Due to eta-reduction in lambda calculus a method value (`f` in this case) can be treated as a function value (`g` in this case) in many cases (where compiler can infer that it needs a function type but instead it is given a method value, sometime due to overloading it's not possible and you need to partially apply your method value with `_` to explicitly tell compiler that you mean it). So I guess it deserves to be mentioned that `f` can be used in many places interchangeably with `g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
f: Int => Int
```

means that type of `f` is `Int => Int`.

Now what does that mean? It means that `f` is a function which gets an `Int` and returns an `Int`.

You can define such a function with

```
def f(i: Int): Int = i * 2
```

or with

```
 def f: Int => Int = i => i * 2
```

or even with

```
def f: Int => Int = _ * 2
```

`_` is a placeholder used for designating the argument. In this case the type of the parameter is already defined in `Int => Int` so compiler knows what is the type of this `_`.

The following is again equivalent to above definitions:

```
def f = (i:Int) => i * 2
```

In all cases type of `f` is `Int => Int`.

### =>

So what is this arrow?
If you see this arrow in type position (i.e. where a type is needed) it designates a function.

for example in

```
val func: String => String
```

But if you see this arrow in an [anonymous function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html) it separates the parameters from body of the function. For example in

```
i => i * 2
```

Comment: ...or `val f = (_: Int) * 2` :)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate just slightly on Nader's answer, f: Int => Int will frequently appear in a parameter list for a high order function, so

```
def myHighOrderFunction(f : Int => Int) : String = {
   // ...
   "Hi"
}
```

is a **dumb** high order function, but shows how you say that myOrderFunction takes as a parameter, f, which is a function that maps an int to an int.

So I might legally call it like this for example:

myHighOrderFunction(_ * 2)

A much more illustrative example comes from Odersky's Programming Scala:

```
object FileMatcher {
    private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
    private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) =
        for (file <- filesHere if matcher(file.getName))
            yield file
    def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))
    def filesContaining(query: String) = filesMatching(_.contains(query))
    def filesRegex(query: String) = filesMatching(_.matches(query))
}
```

Here filesMatching is a high order function, and we define three other functions that call it passing in different anonymous functions to do different kinds of matching.

Hope that helps.